# split groups of values into two columns

Tags: python, list, pandas, split

I have a big list that basically looks like:

```
_list = [('123.45','678.90'), ('098.76', '543.21'),('135.79','246.80')]
```

The parentheses come from another function, so I am unsure if it is part of the output, or if it is placed there as a reference of some sorts.

And I need to split the left values into a left column, with the corresponding right values in another column, where I will have both in a new dataframe:

```
col1 = ['123.45', '098.76','135.79']
col2 = ['678.90', '543.21', '246.80']
new_df = pd.concat([col1, col2])
```

I tried the .split() function, but realized i had multiple commas, so that would include incorrect values : ")" or "(".

Is there something else I can try?

Comment: what is wrong with `df = pd.DataFrame(_list)`?

Comment: I am new to python/pandas so this is all less intuitive for me.. hopefully not forever, haha.

Comment: Well the newness certainly fades.

Comment: Pandas is not really immediately intuitive.  But it is awesome, just the same.  Stick with it, and good luck...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `_list` (**not** `list`, because `list` is a list constructor!) is a list of tuples. The simplest solution is the direct conversion of the list to a DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame(_list)
        0       1
#0  123.45  678.90
#1  098.76  543.21
#2  135.79  246.80
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_list = [('123.45','678.90'), ('098.76', '543.21'),('135.79','246.80')] 
col1= [] 
col2 = [] 
col1.extend([i[0] for i in _list]) 
col2.extend([i[1] for i in _list])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `co1,col2=zip(*_list)` is more elegant. But in any case, that's not what the OP wants.